# How to make Spark JDBC driver show full exception?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I want to get an appropriate exception message from Spark JDBC driver.

My test case:

- Using Spark ver2.0.2 to access DB through JDBC Driver
- At first locked DB, then try write to DB (write mode are append and overwrite)
- Get exception message

Exception message I got:

- case1 append: `Cause already initialized` <-Not good
- case2 overwrite: `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C9008E;00000210;DSN00009.DRITEMRI.00000001, DRIVER=4.19.56` <-Good

My question:

- How can I get an exception message like `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913, SQLSTATE=57033~` in 'case1 append'?
- I guss a reason is function  [savePartitions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala) (this function is called when Spark execute `saveTable`) doesn't show good exception. But I don't know how to fix it.

---

Here is detail exception message of Spark shell

case1 append:

```
scala> prodtbl.write.mode("Append").jdbc(url3,"DB2.D_ITEM_INFO",prop1)
17/04/03 17:50:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cause already initialized

at java.lang.Throwable.setCause(Throwable.java:365)
at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:341)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:300)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:299)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:902)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

case2 overwrite:

```
scala> prodtbl.write.mode("Overwrite").jdbc(url3,"DB2.D_ITEM_INFO",prop1)

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-913,  SQLSTATE=57033, SQLERRMC=00C9008E;00000210;DSN00009.DRITEMRI.00000001, DRIVER=4.19.56

at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.c(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.d(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.i(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.c(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.b(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.h(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.jb(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.a(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.c(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fp.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.dropTable(JdbcUtils.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:422)
... 48 elided
```

Comment: Think about exception rise by DB and those one which originated client such connection refused.

Comment: @FaigB Would you give more detail about your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

So `initCause` described as below:

```
public Throwable initCause(Throwable cause)
```

Initializes the cause of this throwable to the specified value. (The cause is the throwable that caused this throwable to get thrown.)
This method can be called at most once. It is generally called from within the constructor, or immediately after creating the throwable. If this throwable was created with `Throwable(Throwable)` or `Throwable(String,Throwable)`, this method cannot be called even once.

An example of using this method on a legacy throwable type without other support for setting the cause is:

```
try {
     lowLevelOp();
 } catch (LowLevelException le) {
     throw (HighLevelException)
           new HighLevelException().initCause(le); // Legacy constructor
 }
```

**Parameters:**

cause - the cause (which is saved for later retrieval by the getCause() method). (A null value is permitted, and indicates that the cause is nonexistent or unknown.)

**Returns:**

a reference to this Throwable instance.

**Throws:**

`IllegalArgumentException` - if cause is this throwable. (A throwable cannot be its own cause.)
`IllegalStateException` - if this throwable was created with Throwable(Throwable) or Throwable(String,Throwable), or this method has already been called on this throwable.

And it means the cause was something not originated to initialize with `initCase` method and you haven't received what you waited for.